# Testing IO in F#

Tags: f#, tdd

Given i have the IO function:

```
// this can either be IO or some other side effect 
//that makes the function less pure
printf "HI"
```

I want to test that IO was called correctly. An imperative solution for testing that IO was called correctly would be to wrap the IO statement in an object, mock the object, pass the object in using dependency injection, and verify the correct method was called with the correct parameters. I wonder if instead of using dependency injection to test F#, a better way would be checking the output of the function (by asserting that the correct value or function is returned) and stub out the IO call; therefore making the function pure again by eliminating the side effect of an IO call.

I am considering wrapping all IO in a special module like so.

```
let MyPrint print statement = print statement ; statement
```

so that i can stub out the IO function and assert in my tests that the correct operation occurred like so:

code under test:

```
let PrintHi = fun(print) -> MyPrint print "HI"
let DoNothing = fun(print) -> ()

let DoIf conditional = 
     if conditional then PrintHi
     else DoNothing
```

FsUnit:

```
[<Test>] member test.
     let printStub value = ()

     ``Test Hi Is Printed When TRUE`` ()=
          let testedFunc = DoIf true
          testedFunc(printStub) |> should equal PrintHi(printStub)
```

Is this a good way to test IO side effects? Is there a better way? Please keep in mind that my goal is to test any IO, not just a print statement.

Comment: When you do that you are not testing any IO because the possibility of the characters H and I appearing on the console correctly depends on many factors other than printf receiving the passed arguments correctly, such as validity of console handle, GUI flags, IO redirection etc etc and none of those would impact the return value. When you check for return value of the passed arguments you would just be testing F# compiler.

Comment: I am trying to test that my machine (functions) are set up properly. The IO is an expensive operation, and therefore i want to stub it out. I want to make sure that the IO operation is called in the correct way. In an imperative language, you would achieve this with DI and mocks. That doesn't seem to feel right for a functional language.

Comment: I have heard that Haskell gets around this by using monads. I'm not sure if that clarifies the F# solution though.

Comment: "*I want to test that printf was called correctly.*" If it wasn't called correctly, you'd get a compiler error. It is entirely unclear what you actually want to check for.

Comment: I want to check that the string "HI" is passed to printf

Comment: My test should fail if `printf` is called incorrectly. For instance `printf "BYE"` should fail my test

Comment: You're saying that when executing `printf "HI"`, you want to test if `"HI"` is passed to `printf`? In what universe could it _not_ be? Are you trying to test the compiler itself?

Comment: i want to make sure that when `DoIf true` is called, `printf "HI"` is executed. I'm not trying to test printf, i am trying to test DoIf. this is a higher level of testing than unit testing that is very common in large systems.

Comment: I have to say that I'm sort of with @ildjarn on this one--it's hard to tell what you're asking.  If you're asking if there's a way to tell that PrintHi got executed, then why not just change the return type of PrintHi to a boolean and have it return a "true" and the other one return a "false"?

Comment: Ok, and after reading my responses is it still unclear? This is a serious question.

Comment: Having my print statement return a bool is kind of similar to what i am doing in my example. A function with no side effects that returns unit performs no operation. So, on second thought, i think you understand my question a little bit. How can i clarify?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally speaking, you'll want to separate pure code from impure (side-effecting) code; and keep code as pure as possible.

I recommend reading these articles about it, they're written for other functional languages but the code they use is simple and the concepts are well explained and can be easily applied in F# (and many other languages for that matter):

- [Introduction to QuickCheck (Haskell wiki)](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction_to_QuickCheck)
- [How to write a functional program with IO, mutation, and other effects](http://pchiusano.bitbucket.org/presentations/nescala-2012.html#%281%29)

Comment: Second link is dead, I was only able to find https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gZAqJA2pEk, was the original link text?

Answer (score 4):

You could write a wrapper function which temporarily redirects stdout during the call to a function and returns the written values along with the function result:

```
let testPrintf f arg =
    let oldOut = System.Console.Out
    use out = new System.IO.StringWriter()
    System.Console.SetOut(out)
    let res = f arg
    System.Console.SetOut(oldOut)
    (res, out.GetStringBuilder().ToString())
```

Comment: this is more like a mock implementation where i ensure that the correct values were passed in. In functional languages (this is my current understanding) it's more important to test the state that the function returns.

Comment: This is a cool way to do it though. I didn't know you could change the default streamWriter

Answer (score 3):

I guess you don't really want to check if `printf` works as expected (to you?) - I think you want to know if there is some more *functional* way than DI to get testable results.

The answer is twofold:
First: F# is a mixed languague with a big OOP part - so yes I would do your standard DI pattern with interfaces and all that.
Second: instead of using this pattern you can allways use higher-order functions to pass in functions that does for example the IO - in your case something like

```
let myFunctionUsingIO (printer : string -> unit) (whateverparamsYouNeed) = ...
```

and then test this by passing a printer that Asserts whatever your requirements are - but in the end thats the same as having a interface with only one (unnamed) method - so the difference is very small.

PS: if you only interessted in the return value - just do normal unit-testing - if you write your functions pure there is no need to test anything different, but then your example was ... well poor, because `printf` is the opposite of pure...

Comment: exactly. printf is where my problem lies. if it returned a value, than i could do pure testing. (Is this a common saying? Pure testing?)

Comment: put it would be useless for printf to return a value - as the function of this is only the side-effect of printing something to the users console - if you want you could say that you have to test this with acceptance-tests, but this is no different from testing say in C# - and as this function is a very low level framework method there is no need to test it at all - normaly you only want to test your own code - just think of it - to you want to test things like `+` and `if` also? With unit tests?

Comment: I don't want to test the F# framework. Here's a larger example. What if, instead of a printf statement, I have a db call or network call. I want to assert that the correct info was passed to the db or network. In imperative frameworks, you would mock out the db dependency and assert the db call was done correctly. This is testing with DI. I am trying to achieve the same level of test ability, but without using DI. Does this make my intent more clear?

Comment: No the ident was clear - as I said use your normal test pattern - what should be the problem with this?

Comment: The problem with using mocks (the normal test pattern) would be mocking out function behavior. Which i don't believe a F# test library exists for yet. When i looked into why this is (maybe i could write one) it seems as if the purists don't use mocks. I was curious if the pattern i was using above is a way to achieve that level of testing without mocks.

Comment: also, if you use normal unit testing, when your function only does IO, your function will return unit. In the functional world that has no side effects, a function that returns unit does nothing.

Comment: First: there are Mocking-Frameworks that are *usable* in F# (sadly not MOQ, but RhinoMocks and others are working fine)

Comment: Then you can just use the extended OOP-caps of F# to write your mocks on the go : `{new IMyinterface with ...}`

Comment: And of course: don't let yourself be cornered because you **have** to make something functional only to be pure - do what's working reasonably fast - and if it's unit-testing with DI - no problem

Comment: I understand the practicality of getting work done. But i'm trying to create a testing strategy for using F# as a purely functional language.

Comment: Do you know if RhinoMocks allows you to mock out first class functions? I don't want to use concrete mocks because maintaining them can be a pain for large software projects.

Comment: in the end a first-class function is nothing more than a (better) delegate like `Func<,>` in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340302.aspx